# Linked Postgresql to Mssql Error

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, linked-server

I've successfully linked postgresql and mssql using psqlodbc, mssql can now list tables from postgresql. But this error occured when I execute an sql

`Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRES32" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRES32".`

using

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(POSTGRES32,'SELECT * FROM categories')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(POSTGRES32,'SELECT * FROM public.categories')
```

How can I fix this error? thanks!

Comment: Do You have proper rights for accessing this tables?

Comment: How can I set this rights?

Comment: on postgres side. Create user, or check if user You are contecting using OLE DBp has proper rights.